# Слово ВЫСЛУШАН: какая часть речи / синтаксическая роль?

Tags: синтаксис, части-речи

В предложении:

> Рассказ Аннушки о вылетающих из окна дома на Садовой людях и о подковке, которую Аннушка, по ее словам, подняла для того, чтобы предъявить в милицию, был выслушан внимательно.

в конструкции

> рассказ был выслушан

какой частью речи является слово *выслушан*?

Answer (score 2):

Выслушан - краткая форма причастия 'выслушанный'. 
Следовательно, выслушан - краткое причастие.

Comment: Краткое страдательное причастие плюс глагол "быть" в роли вспомогательного, употреблён в прошедшем времени. Одна из форм того самого пассивного залога ( пассив прошедшего времени),  о желательности обучения которому недавно высказывалась   Vera.

Answer (score 2):

Выслушан - это краткое страдательное причастие, которое в предложение всегда является частью составного именного сказуемого.